# c# json сериализованный

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В теле запроса имеется сериализованные json данные, как в asp core 2 описывается метод пост, чтобы эти данные вытянуть, нужно ли [FromBody] ?

Comment: да. [FromBody] десериализует данные в конкретный тип

Comment: То есть мне нужно создать связующую модель для принятия значений ? И обязательно ли в этой модели наименование переменных должны совпадать? Или можно так a1 = a2

Comment: asp.net core 2 использует Newtonsoft.Json (в версии 3 будет свое использовать) и значит работает по тем же правилам, что и JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString) с его конвенциями или [JsonProperty("varname")], а конвертеры регистрировать в services.AddJsonOptions. Подойдет любой класс, в который сможет десериализоваться json, но я предпочитаю делать вьюмодели дополнительно к обычным моделям и вот на эти вьюмодели и происходит маппинг (так безопаснее)